# Prevent or override map resolution recalculation on window and canvas resize for custom map scale

Tags: javascript, openlayers

When manually setting a custom resolution on an Openlayers map it will be reverted if there is any change to the window or canvas size.

I'm intentionally overrendering the map in order to get a higher resolution image. The resolution is a function of the canvas size, desired Pixels per Inch and document size. While the tiles are loading and the function for the rendercomplete event is loaded I would like to prevent the default resize of the map.

This can be reproduced on the [OpenLayers examples page for PDF export](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-pdf.html)

1. Export something that will take enough time that it can be interrupted.
2. Resize the window
3. Observe the rescale of the map and the exported page at the wrong resolution

Is there any way to capture and recalculate, override or prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The resolution isn't changing, the window resize is causing OpenLayers to reset the canvas size set by `map.setSize(printSize)` back to the div size.  If you put the map div inside a container div

```
  .container {
    width: 566px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

remove the `max-width` CSS and set and clear the div size

```
    map.getTargetElement().style.height = height + 'px';
    map.getTargetElement().style.width = width + 'px';
    map.setSize([width, height]);

      map.setSize(size);
      map.getTargetElement().style.height = '';
      map.getTargetElement().style.width = '';
```

it seems to works.